# Getting html select value on postback

Tags: asp.net, razor, umbraco

I'm having a bit of trouble here, hoping someone can help:

I am dynamically populating an html select element in a razor script and onChange I am hoping to get this posted value.
It is posting back as the page is refreshing but I don't seem to be getting the value of the select; The reason I know is that I am passing a category and filtering on it. This filtering works when I change the querystring in the URL manually and post it.

Razor Script:

```
   @using umbraco.MacroEngines
@inherits DynamicNodeContext
@{
    dynamic rootNode = @Model.NodeById(1066);
    DynamicNodeList list = rootNode.Descendants();
    List<dynamic> categories = new List<dynamic>(list.Cast<dynamic>());
    List<string> alias = new List<string> { "GeneralPage" };
    var filtered = categories.Where(n => alias.Contains(n.NodeTypeAlias));    
}
<form method="post" action="">
<select id="selectCategory" name="selectCategory" onchange="this.form.submit(); alertMe(selectCategory)">
    @foreach (var node in filtered)
    {
        <option value="@node.Name">@node.Name</option>
    }
</select>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function alertMe(selectCategory) {
        alert(selectCategory)
    }
</script>
```

You'll notice I have a function to alert the selected value but this is coming back as [object HTMLSelectElement]

I can post more code if needed to show what's happening on the server, but as I said the filtering DOES work, however I am trying capture the value in the following way:

```
string category = Request["selectCategory"];
            if (category != null)
            {
```

Any help much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
ViewContext.RouteData.Values["selectCategory"]
```

As for the javascript, you are passing in the dom reference to the select list, not the selected item. If you want to see the value of it, you need to use

```
alert(selectCategory.value)
```